# How can I generate a string of size 10, through rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-migration

I have a rails 3.2.14 app with `mysql` database.

I have the following `migration` :

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games,:options => 'CHARSET=utf8' do |t|
      t.char :recsts
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

and I get a error,because `char` isn't supported.  Besides, `t.string` will generate `varchar(255)` but what I need is `nvarchar(10)`.

So I want to know is there a solution for this, if not I will have to give up the Rails DB Migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the :limit attribute:

```
t.string :rects, :limit => 10
```